# Change the URL navigation in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

While I Finishing my job in my main page; It is the time to go to the nest razor Page.
I try to do that from the next page controller `loginController`.
While I'm in the main controller I use the following `sub` for this purpose:

```
Public Sub FlagBtn_Click(ByVal myFlag As String)
        Attributes.envProp._LanguageFlag = myFlag
        Attributes.mvcLogin.Index()
    End Function
```

The program goes to the next controller `loginController` and executes the function there:

```
<Route("Login")>    
      Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function
```

Which normally has to change the `url` as well according to the `route file`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "main", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
```

But that doesn't happen. Instead of that the `url` navigation remains on the `Default` route which is `http://localhost:12345/main` and of course the next page can't be display, because is in another `subfolder` `http://localhost:12345/Login` .
The question here is how to change the `url` navigation, according to page I choose to go.
   **ADDITION 23/2/19 23:45**
The call for the controller `main` starts from a `ajax` script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FlagBtnOnClick(flag) {
        var flagName = flag;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("FlagBtn_Click")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { myFlag: flagName },
        });
```

That is happen because I need to assign a value to a property which is done it very well:

```
Public Sub FlagBtn_Click(ByVal myFlag As String) ' As ActionResult
        Attributes.envProp._LanguageFlag = myFlag
    End Sub
```

After that there is one more `ajax` script:

```
Login();
function Login() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '@Url.Action("../login/Index")',
  dataType: 'json',
        });
}
```

With that script I call the next controller... `loginController`
And I have a `Sub` named `Index` :

```
 Public Sub Index()  
        Response.Redirect("../Views/Login/Index")
    End Sub
```

That is my tryout to change the `url navigation bar`. And finally to call the `Index.aspx` file there.

**ADDITION 24/2/19  00:06**
I've noticed that even I type the address in the `url` bar 
`http://localhost:49254/Views/Login/Index`
The browser threw me an error of "404 Not Found". which is crazy because the file is there and works very nice.

**ADDITION 24/2/19  20:20**
Finally with the grate assistance of mr.Jasen I made the following changes which they led me to the desired result as follows:
At the `mainController` I put this function:

```
Public Function FlagBtn_Click(ByVal myFlag As String) As JsonResult
        Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
        Attributes.envProp._LanguageFlag = myFlag
        Return Json(New With {Key .myUrl = "Login/Index"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function
```

Be very careful withe the line

```
Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
```

That is absolutely need it because for some **""reason""** `Microsoft` resides to make our life's more complex (ma be for security reasons) and have this attribute `RouteExistingFiles` to false
Thus the MVC doesn't understands the physical paths nor the existing files.
In the `LayoutPage` I have the following scripts:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function FlagBtnOnClick(flag){
        var flagName = flag;
        var call = '@Url.Action("FlagBtn_Click")';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: call,
            data: { myFlag: flagName },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                data.myUrl;
                SendToController(data.myUrl);
            },
        });
    }
    function SendToController(url) {
        var innerUrl = '@Url.Action("Index")';
            $.ajax({
                url: innerUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("body").html(data);
                    document.location = url; },
            });
        }
</script>
```

With which I `manage` the `button_click` event (with the first) and on the return from the `mainController` I take the new `physical path` and assign it to the `url navigator of my browser
And of course I call the next 'loginController' like that:

```
 Public Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
        Return View()
    End Function
```

So there I have it... 
The new page is in front of my screen.
Of course I'm facing other issues.. like..
While I'm in my new page.. and I push the left arrow in my browser then it send me back to the first page
That's OK... normal... Now I click in the button on my main page in order to go (again) in the login page...
Fault... the action never takes place... The same happen when I press the right arrow in my browser... It's not so crusual issue... but it is an issue which needs to solve it
I really hope that I help any other potential developer which is facing same issues.
Thanks mr.Jasen

Comment: Show us your main controller and the view that triggers the FlagBtn_Click.

Comment: Please look in my Addition 23/2/19

Comment: The first thing that stands out is an AJAX call will not change the URL. We typically use AJAX when we do not want to navigate away from the original page. You will need to explicitly navigate to your Index page in the ajax response handler (which you have not even specified).

Comment: You should also review how routing and URL work with MVC as your question demonstrates a basic misunderstanding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc668201(v=vs.140)

Comment: At the end of the day I finish what I was need and I have a success story... But now I'm facing a new issue which is not critical but it an issue. I'm in my new page.. OK... and I push the `left arrow` in my browser then it send me back to the first page, that's OK... normal... Now I click in the button of flag in order to go (again) in the login page... That's fault... the action never takes place...

Comment: @Jasen Please make your comment as an answer in order to vote for it.